# Java mongodb aggregation count occurrences

Tags: java, mongodb

I have some documents like this:

```
{
  "user": '1'
},
{ "user": '1'
},
{
  "user": '2'
},
{
  "user": '3'
}
```

I'd like to be able to get a set of all the different users and their respective counts, sorted in decreasing order. So my output would be something like this:

```
{
  '1': 2,
  '2': 1,
  '3': 1
}
```

So, in mongodb is :

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   {$group : { _id : '$user', count : {$sum : 1}}}
).result
```

But I want to do this in java. I tried this:

```
AggregateIterable it = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        group("$id", Accumulators.sum("$user", 1)),
        sort(Sorts.descending("$user"))
));
```

But it's wrong... How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
AggregateIterable it = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
    group("$user", Accumulators.sum("count", 1)),
    sort(Sorts.descending("count"))
));
```

Comment: thanks!, how can I do if I want to show another field of the document?

Comment: You can calculate another field as part of a group like this: `group("$customerId", sum("totalQuantity", "$quantity"), avg("averageQuantity", "$quantity"))`, however, if you want fields from the original document to come up, try using facet.